# Promises call their success callback too late

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have a code as follows:

```
products.SaveApplications = function (product) {
    var promises = [];

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(product.Applications(), function (item) {
       var applicationToSend = ko.mapping.toJS(item);
       promises.push($.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/json",
             url: serviceUrl + "/InsertApplication",
             data: JSON.stringify(applicationToSend),
             success: function (data) {
                 alert("Doing success callback now.");
                 item.ID(data);
             }}));
    });

    return promises;
}
```

Then a function `products.SaveEnvironments`, which is basically the same, except it calls a different function in my controller, and a function `products.SaveInstallations`, which is, again, mostly the same, except it needs to wait for Environments and Applications to save, because it has some dependant data (Application.ID and Environment.ID).

Now I have a function, which calls both these functions and waits for them until both have finished:

```
products.SaveChanges = function (product) {
    // (...)
    var promises = products.SaveApplications(product);
    promises = promises.concat(products.SaveEnvironments(product));

    $.when(promises).done(function () {
       alert("we shouldn't see this before the other message!");
       products.SaveInstallations(product);
    }); 
};
```

The problem is that the alert box with "We shouldn't see this message before the other message!" actually appears before the "Doing success callback now", which means my ID properties are null at the time. It leads me to the conclusion that the `$.when` call only does the actual promises, but doesn't wait for the success callbacks to finish. How can I make it wait? Thank you.

Comment: Try switching `.success` to `.then` there, that'll cause it to return a new promise, also - add `return data` to the end of it after changing it to a `.then`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I appreciate it. :) Sadly, it still does the exact same thing. :(

Comment: Can you change your code in this sample to not use `.postJSON` as I'm unfamiliar with it? A regular `$.ajax` might make the problem easier to spot.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was on my lunch break. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Don't use `success: function(){` use `.then`

Comment: The answer below works for me. Thank you very much for your efforts, though, I really do appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) incorrectly. You can't pass multiple promises to it as an array; if you do that, it treats the array just like any other non-promise value and turns it into a completed promise with the array of the still-pending promises as its result. That, of course, is not useful.

You need to use `.apply` instead to simulate calling `$.when` with each promise as a separate argument, like this:

```
$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function () { ... });
```